# How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql

I got a not solvable problem with a SELECT statement in a PHP script.
This Query is doing it's job, however i need to expand it too get the values from a particular column.

`

```
$r = DBi::$conn->query('
        SELECT 
            a.pKey,
            a.Name,
            a.`Pic-Name`,
            a.GTIN,
            a.Type,
            a.Avail,
            (SELECT Price FROM preise WHERE Art_pKey = a.pKey ORDER BY From_date DESC LIMIT 1) Price,
            (AVG((b.Preice / b.Art_Num) * -1.00)) Mid_price,
            a.Created
      FROM art a LEFT
        JOIN kasse b ON a.pKey = b.Art_pKey
     WHERE Aktiv = "Y" AND Avail = "Y" AND Visible = "Y"
     GROUP BY a.pKey
     ORDER BY Avail DESC, Name ASC
    ') or trigger_error('Query Failed! SQL: ' . $r . ' - Error: ' . mysqli_error(DBi::$conn), E_USER_ERROR);
```

`

Again, this query is doing its job. But now i'm trying to replace the `SELECT Price FROM...` part with a variable.

I put this prior the query:

`

```
 if ($_SESSION['user']['Organisation'] == 'DEPT1'){
        $varPriceCol = 'PriceDEPT1';
    }
    elseif ($_SESSION['user']['Organisation'] == 'DEPT2'){
        $varPriceCol = 'PriceDEPT2';
    }
    else{
        $varPriceCol = 'Price';`
```

But as soon, as i'm doing it this way: `(SELECT "$varPriceCol" FROM preise WHERE Art_pKey = a.pKey ORDER BY From_date DESC LIMIT 1) Price` the query stops working. If i place the "PriceDEPT1" or "PriceDEPT2" or "Price" instead of a variable the query starts working for any of the 3 colum names.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change quotes of your query to double quotes, as PHP will not substitute strings with variables if query is single-qouted. Also, inside your query you need to change string literals to single quotes, so it complies with SQL syntax.

Something like that:

```
$r = DBi::$conn->query(" -- <<< note double quote
        SELECT 
            a.pKey,
            a.Name,
            a.`Pic-Name`,
            a.GTIN,
            a.Type,
            a.Avail,
            (SELECT $varPriceCol FROM preise WHERE Art_pKey = a.pKey ORDER BY From_date DESC LIMIT 1) Price,
            (AVG((b.Preice / b.Art_Num) * -1.00)) Mid_price,
            a.Created
      FROM art a LEFT
        JOIN kasse b ON a.pKey = b.Art_pKey
     WHERE Aktiv = 'Y' AND Avail = 'Y' AND Visible = 'Y' -- <<< note single quotes
     GROUP BY a.pKey
     ORDER BY Avail DESC, Name ASC
    ") or trigger_error('Query Failed! SQL: ' . $r . ' - Error: ' . mysqli_error(DBi::$conn), E_USER_ERROR);
```

Answer (score 2):

When selecting columns you need to use backticks to delimit them:

```
SELECT `$varPriceCol` FROM ...
```

You'll also want to be *extremely* certain that this variable contains only known-good values. Your `if` chain is a good example of this, but you could do one better by using a lookup array:

```
$columnMap = array('DEPT1' => 'PriceDEPT1', 'DEPT2' => 'PriceDEPT2');
$columnMapDefault = 'Price';
```

That minimizes the amount of junk in your `if` statement if used correctly. When writing code like this try and avoid endless repetition, that's how mistakes are made.

The other thing you can do is `SELECT *` and just pick the column you want out of the results set.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that backticks are not working in this case. And i don't know why.

Comment: @0xbadc0de "Not working" is a meaningless phrase. Do you get an error? Does the query return the wrong results? Be more specific, please. Using single or double quotes is just plain wrong, that will return a constant string not a value from the column.

Comment: The query does not return anything if using backticks.  If i try to print the $r co console after the statement all i get is  a "false" printed out.  The same case if i try to select non existing column.

Comment: You should have [the documentation to `mysqli` open at all times](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) when writing code like this because that would tell you `false` indicates the query had an error. You should [enable exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578243/turning-query-errors-to-exceptions-in-mysqli) to make these errors show up more clearly.

Comment: Also as @amaksr noted, [remember how PHP handles string interpolation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). This is a very important thing to remember.